# How to initialize an object dynamically in the program?

Tags: c++, object, dynamic

How to initialize object dynamically in the program without inheritance in c++?
For example i Have class A and class B. And depend on condition i need to create instance of object but i don't know exactly what object i need to create, it depends on information that user input;

Example code:

```
int i;
cin>>i>>endl;
void *obj;
if(i)
    obj = new A();
else
    obj = new B();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting Class Pointer to Void Pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929225/casting-class-pointer-to-void-pointer)

Comment: Why do you want to avoid inheritance? If you need to be able to store either of the two classes in one variable, then classes have to have something in common. If they have something in common, then inheritance is natural solution.

Comment: it only one way? but if i have class of matrix and class of Vector? Do you think that it good choice first of all create abstract class?

Comment: You have two paths in your code. One for Vector and one for Matrix. You want to have a variable which is capable of holding either of the two, so I assume those two code paths join later in, i.e. there's some `do_something_with_either_matrix_or_vector(obj);` function call. That means both Vector and Matrix share some properties, which in turn means that yes, abstract class (think interface in java/c#) would be good fit.

Comment: If you don't like dynamic polymorphism, then static polymorphism with templates might suit you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [std::any](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) or [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) depending on your needs.

Casting a pointer to `void*` is (most of the time) a bad idea because you loose the type of the object and you have to deal with raw pointer. Which means that you have to manage resources, call the right destructor... `any` and `variant` do that for you.

I would recommend using `variant` and not `any`, unless you have a specific need for `any` because `variant`give you more control over the type: your value can have only a limited list of type.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have limitation of taking pointers then take two pointers of both classes and initialize the one according to input.

```
int i;
A *a_ptr;
B *b_ptr;
cin>>i>>endl;
if(i)
    a_ptr = new A();
else
    b_ptr = new B();
```

Comment: i know that, but may i create only one pointer and initialize object that i need?